# Snap UV vertex to a vertex belonging to a different object

Tags: vertices, snapping, uv-image-editor

I need to line up one side (border to border) of two UV faces in the UV editor. The problem is that these UV faces belongs to two different objects.

It seems like snapping only works within the same object.

Is there any way to make it snap to vertices of another object (UV editor).

Comment: (Sorry if this is dumb and if it isn't practical. This happens to be hte quickest hack I can think of.) You can use the right-hand-side panel in the UV-editor (N key to open) to set vertexes' positions accurately. (Select the vertex you want to align with. Then go to the properties panel. Then look for the properties bound to the x and y of the vertex. Copy them to the other mesh's x and y.)

Comment: That would be a bit too tedious :) So far I merged the objects, made my UV and then split the object again... But a snap to UV vertices across objects would be perfect.

Comment: It's awful, but if you absolutely had to do it, that would be the way (afaik.). One possible way (Sadly I can't  credit the original inventor of the technique because I don't know who it is.) is to use rip (V key) in the 3D view to cut the islands by hand. Then add a shapekey and move vertices around until you have everything on a plane. Then you could snap to the thing from other meshes. When the layout is done, you would use U > Project from View on the two meshes. Then move them back to the original position using the shapekeys and use W > Remove Doubles to restore the original mesh.

Comment: Sorry if this is more confusing than it is useful.

Comment: Related? http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30668/arrange-uv-maps-of-multiple-objects-without-joining-them

Comment: @Gonzou, no I want to snap UV vertices to another object's UV vertices. I know how to see all objects on the same UV map.